# Storing images in Phones having both inbuilt storage and external SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am trying to store an image in the external storage by using getExternalStorageDirectory() method. I want to know if a phone has both inbuilt external storage and also an external SD Card too. Where will be the image stored first ? If one of these storage is full, will the system use the other storage to store the image ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the [official document](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) to handle saving files. There are no automatic method to save image if the storage full but you can check the storage's space using  `getFreeSpace()` or `getTotalSpace()` which available in Android API. Android give the flexibility to the developer to handle file's storage.